# Can't unmount ext 4 in gparted

Tags: gparted, swap, ext4, unmount, unallocated

I wanted to add extra swap to my pc I followed lots of tutorials but i needed to make a unallocated partition and for that I needed to unmount ext4
I'm totally new in Ubuntu or linux 
Anybody a suggestion?

Comment: If the ext4 partition is actively used by the currently running operating system, then you will not be able to unmount it.  Instead boot from live media, such as the Ubuntu Live CD, or [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and perform your partitioning from there.

Comment: tnx you are right

Answer (score -1):

I have not had this problem but try just unplugging if it is not doing any work.

```
sudo umount /mnt/share
```